# How to disable CRC checks in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, crc

Afer adding a symbol index to some debug symbol file I get a CRC mismatch on gdb:

```
warning: the debug information found in "/xxx/yyy/lib/debug/libzzz.so" does not match "target:/lib/libzzz.so" (CRC mismatch)
```

Is there are a general settings in gdb to disable all sanity checks while loading files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no setting to disable the CRC check when loading a separate debug file.